# Mongodb - Encontrar vendas que contenham dois produtos

Tags: mongodb

Sou iniciante no Mongodb e gostaria de ajuda com a seguinte questão.
Tenho uma collection que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
{[{id_venda:1, id_produto:20},
  {id_venda:1, id_produto:3332},
  {id_venda:1, id_produto:9},
  {id_venda:2, id_produto:20},
  {id_venda:2, id_produto:9},
  {id_venda:2, id_produto:7}
  {id_venda:3, id_produto:2980},
  {id_venda:4, id_produto:217}]}
```

Como eu posso encontrar as vendas que contenha os produtos 9 e 20?
Nesse caso o resultado retornado seria: 1 e 2

Código que tentei:

```
db.vendas.find({id_produto:{$elemMatch:{$eq:9,$eq:20}}})
```

Porém sei que não está certo, porque o código acima aplica o filtro no mesmo objeto e eu gostaria de aplicar em cima do id_venda

Agradeço antecipadamente que puder me ajudar

Comment: Está usando o mongodb com nde.js? Poste o código que já tentou! E como está a estrurura das coleções de produtos e vendas?

Comment: A estrutura da venda é essa que postei. No banco relacional seria algo como uma chave primária composta, onde a venda pode o id_venda pode se repetir desde que o Id_produto seja diferente.

Comment: Estou utilizando o shell do MongoDb

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi, essa coleção que postou parece ser uma tabela resultante de uma relação N:N entre produtos e vendas, estou certo? Se sim coloque a estrutura da coleção de produtos e da coleção de vendas

Comment: Não, no Mongodb não temos tabelas e sim collections, dentro da Collection vendas
tenho esse objeto que é representado por essa estrutura JSON.
Os conceitos de Banco Relacional não se aplicam aqui.

Comment: Tabelas e coleções são essencialmente a mesma coisa com nomes diferentes, apesar de diferentes, conceitos de SQL podem e são aplicados a NoSQL. Por exemplo, o mongodb tem o `agregate` (ou algo assim) equivalente ao `JOIN` do SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

      //Primeiro filtro pelas vendas que contenha um dos produtos     
{$match:{$or:[{id_produto:9},{id_produto:20}]}},


      //Agrupo pelo id da venda contando a quantidade de vezes que aparece um 
     //registro (cada registro encontrado é referente a um dos produtos)     
{$group:{_id:"$id_venda",count:{$sum:1}}},

    //Então eu filtro onde foram encontrados os dois produtos
{$match:{"count":2}}
])
```